# How to change Bootstrap's .table-responsive to something better like Stackable.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Creating responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px) is nice.

But I want something better for my clients so that they won't have to scroll to see the whole table. Stacktable.js is much better because it creates a copy of the table that is converted into a 2-column key/value format.

My question is how do I integrate the stackable.js code to my Bootstrap so that I can eliminate the scrolling features of the .table-responsive and just use the beautiful features of Stacktable.js?